# Why does sklearn logistic regression regularize both the weights and the intercept?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

The regularization parameter C in logistic regression 
(see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) is used allow the function to be fitted to be well defined and avoid either overfitting or problems with step functions (see https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10805/does-scikit-learn-use-regularization-by-default/10806).

However, regularization in logistic regression should only concern the weights for the features, not the intercept (also explained here: http://aimotion.blogspot.com/2011/11/machine-learning-with-python-logistic.html)

But is seems that sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression actually regularizes the intercept as well. Here is why:

1) Conside above link carefully (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10805/does-scikit-learn-use-regularization-by-default/10806): the sigmod is moved slightly to the left, closer to the intercept 0.

2) I tried to fit data points with a logistic curve and a manual maximum likelihood function. Including the intercept into the L2 norm gives identical results as sklearn's function.

Two questions please:

1) Did I get this wrong, is this a bug, or is there a well-justified reason for regularizing the intercept?

2) Is there a way to use sklearn and specify to regularize all parameters except the intercepts?

Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

C = 1e1
model = LogisticRegression(C=C)

x = np.arange(100, 110)
x = x[:, np.newaxis]
y = np.array([0]*5 + [1]*5)

print x
print y

model.fit(x, y)
a = model.coef_[0][0]
b = model.intercept_[0]

b_modified = -b/a                   # without regularization, b_modified should be 104.5 (as for C=1e10)

print "a, b:", a, -b/a

# OUTPUT: 
# [[100]
#  [101]
#  [102]
#  [103]
#  [104]
#  [105]
#  [106]
#  [107]
#  [108]
#  [109]]
# [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
# a, b: 0.0116744221756 100.478968664
```

Comment: I asked a similar question several years ago. I know you can use the argument intercept_scaling to control this but I’m not sure of the appropriate technique. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711304/how-to-set-intercept-scaling-in-scikit-learn-logisticregression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scikit-learn has default regularized logistic regression.

The change in  `intercept_scaling` parameter value in `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` has similar effect on the result if only `C` parameter is changed.

In case of modification in `intercept_scaling` parameter, regularization has an impact on the estimation of bias in logistic regression. When this parameter's value is on higher side then the regularization impact on bias is reduced. Per [official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html):

> The intercept becomes `intercept_scaling * synthetic_feature_weight`. 
>   Note! the synthetic feature weight is subject to l1/l2 regularization
>   as all other features. To lessen the effect of regularization on
>   synthetic feature weight (and therefore on the intercept)
>   intercept_scaling has to be increased.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I added a minimum example. Can you please illustrate with this example what needs to be added to not regularize the intercept? Thanks!

Comment: I think that if you make the intercept scaling arbitrarily large, the regularization of it will be negligible (but not strictly zero)

Comment: As @cxrodgers has rightly pointed out - let's try `model = LogisticRegression(intercept_scaling=99999)`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Prem, this is indeed the solution:

```
C = 1e1  
intercept_scaling=1e3    # very high numbers make it unstable in practice
model = LogisticRegression(C=C, intercept_scaling=intercept_scaling)
```